# JSON Multiple Key Value Print

Tags: python, json, data-analysis

I have some JSON data that i want to analyze for speed and respective timestamp and i have gotten this far. I have reverse sorted it and also plotted a graph using matplotlib. Now i wanted to output the Key with corresponding value but i am only able to print the speed key and not the timestamp key.

```
import json
import datetime
import pprint
from operator import itemgetter
import natsort
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd




#path to gps data file in json format.
data_file = "waypoints.json"


def speed_ans(self, data_file):
    pass


"""
def visualize_type(output):
    #Visualize data by category in a bar graph

    #This returns a dict where it sums the total per Category.
    counter = Counter(item["Speed"] for item in output)

    # Set the labels which are based on the keys of our counter.
    labels = tuple("Speed")

    # Set where the labels hit the x-axis
    xlocations = np.arange(len(labels)) + 0.5

    # Width of each bar
    width = 0.5

    # Assign data to a bar plot
    plt.bar(xlocations, counter.values(), width=width)

    # Assign labels and tick location to x- and y-axis
    plt.xticks(xlocations + width / 2, labels, rotation=90)
    plt.yticks(range(0, max(counter.values()), 5))

    # Give some more room so the labels aren't cut off in the graph
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4)

    # Make the overall graph/figure larger
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12, 8

    # Save the graph!
    plt.savefig("Graph.png")

    plt.clf()
 """

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(data_file) as f:
        waypoints = json.load(f)

    sorted_waypoints = natsort.natsorted(waypoints, key=itemgetter(*['Speed']), reverse = True)
    #pprint.pprint(sorted_waypoints)

    for e in sorted_waypoints:
        for k, v in e.items():
            if k == 'Speed' and v >= 6:
                print k, v
```

waypoints.json File :

```
[{
    "Latitude": 1.282143333,
    "Timestamp": 1434368770,
    "Speed": 7.696,
    "Longitude": 103.850785
}, {
    "Latitude": 1.282205,
    "Timestamp": 1434368771,
    "Speed": 7.233,
    "Longitude": 103.850806667
}, {
    "Latitude": 1.282205,
    "Timestamp": 1434368772,
    "Speed": 7.233,
    "Longitude": 103.850806667
}, {
    "Latitude": 1.282205,
    "Timestamp": 1434368773,
    "Speed": 7.444,
    "Longitude": 103.850806667
}, {
    "Latitude": 1.282261667,
    "Timestamp": 1434368774,
    "Speed": 6.933,
    "Longitude": 103.850833333
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this help.

```
for e in sorted_waypoints:
    for k, v in e.items():
        if (k == 'Speed' or k == 'Timestamp') and v >= 5:
        print k, v
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but the output is not what i desired. It has some unwanted stuff in the output.

Comment: The O/P is like this 
Speed 5.33
Timestamp 1434367770
Speed 5.222
Timestamp 1434367550
Speed 5.196
Timestamp 1434368742
Speed 5.0
Timestamp 1434367211
Timestamp 1434367212
Timestamp 1434367542
Timestamp 1434367895
Timestamp 1434368746
Timestamp 1434367378

The Speed + Timestamp combo is fine but after that a long sequence of timestamps is being printed out :|

Answer (score -1):

The reason you're printing only the speed key is because you are checking for the key value to be "Speed" before printing. All you have to do is modify the condition to what you want to print.

Comment: I tried doing that earlier but did not work out, i fixed the issue with the help of the previous commenter. Anyway thanks for your help too :)